# a cancel link isn't correctly working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

after inspecting the element on google chrome tools

```
<a class="_cancelRxSelection" href="javascript:void(0)">Cancel</a>
```

And I had found that in the code:

```
$('a._cancelRxSelection', self.el).click(function() {
            $('div._configRx', el).remove();
        });
    },
```

it's just a cancel link that supposed to cancel after a button has been clicked.
I know this is fairly broad but what are some things i can look at?

I tried el).hide(); instead of remove(); still of no effect

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Your question does not contain a clear problem description. What is happening? What is expected..? *"it's just a cancel link that supposed to cancel after a button has been clicked"* cancel what? which button? What does the button do? how does the button invoke the hyperlinks click..? please read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `href="javascript:void(0)"`. Also, add a `.preventDefault()` inside the original `click` handler. ie:

```
$('a._cancelRxSelection', self.el).click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
            $('div._configRx', el).remove();
        });
    })
```

Comment: That should do it, i normally also add `return false;` just to be safe. But this is far from backbone-esk. Still, i'll upvote you :D

Comment: I’m not sure how this is going to make any difference. `e.preventDefault()` would cancel the default click action. But the default is “nothing”, because the `href` is `javascript:void(0)` anyway. Can you elaborate a bit further what difference it would make?

Comment: `void()` is built in, and it takes 1 param. I normally hate seeing them. Much rather see `#` in the url highlight, do my code in the bound click function (in backbone if i may add) and then doing the `return false;` (personal preference)

Comment: @JavierBuzzi `void` isn’t a function, but a keyword which works like a unary operator, so it doesn’t take 1 param, but 1 operand. Anyway, my personal preference for links that execute JavaScript instead of refering to another page is: _don’t use links_ that execute JavaScript instead of refering to another page. A button would be a better choice here.

Comment: @Xufox You're right. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void  and yes i would agree with you on the : `don’t use links that execute JavaScript instead of refering to another page`

Comment: @Xufox unfortunately there has been no error log i can access... any other suggestions? i am trying to see if the above will work or not

Comment: @purple_rein I think you meant to reply to “Bwaxxlo” or “Javier_Buzzi” or you should have replied on your question, not on this answer. So, if you press F12 on Firefox or Chrome and access the JS console, there’s no error shown?